# Wordpress single core install with thousands of sites

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a single Wordpress install that contains thousands of sites. Currently it's set up so that each site has it's own directory where themes, plugins and uploads are stored. I chose not to use multi-site because I need individual sites to be able to manage their own themes and plugins. This part is all good, it's the database I'm worried about.

With each new site new database tables are created with prefix wp_siteName_.

The issue I'm having is that with the potential for thousands of sites, my database will be loaded with tables. Especially if users add plugins that also add more tables.

Currently, new tables are created by a change to wp-config.php.

I changed this line:

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_'.$site;
```

With **$site** being unique to each new website. This will bring up the install page to create the new tables if they don't already exist.

Can this be a huge performance issue or should it be okay? If it is a performance issue, is there any way to share DB tables between sites or some other alternative all together?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I don't think you should be too worried. It may seem like it is a lot of data to handle, but the db can handle it. I guess it all depends on how big your db is and how many reads and writes you will perform per site every second. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: The sites will be of all different sizes and ran by different users. So it's tough to say how many reads and writes.